# Spline bevel thickness

Tags: bezier-curves

Is there a simple, sure-fire way of just beveling a spline without it constantly either twisting or breaking or whatever else? I'd like to think i'm at least of an intermediate skill level with Blender, but i still can't get my head round Blender's splines. A different spline, a different experience. All i want is to bevel a spline and have the bevel thickness be the same throughout its length. This is as close as i got.[image]

The weight, the radius and the tilt (1,1,0) is the same on all the vertices. The LocRotScale on the spline were applied numerous times.

Would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: do u need like pipe bevel or what type of bevel u need

Comment: @atek Right now i just want a simple round bevel

Comment: u can have the quick pipe addon https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBNbwyOwesE&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to switch to 2d shape because it makes better defined corners.
 If you want to optimize for render convert to mesh using <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>.
Then add a decimate modifier and play with the ratio value until you got the looks that you want.

[image]

Comment: Alt C is convert to mesh/spline for me. Can you please point it out to me in the interface?

Comment: Yes. Step 2 and 3 is only for cleanup.
First pic is before!

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked fine. It looks pretty clean, just like in your picture, even without the 2nd and the 3rd step though.

Comment: Please add some more details to your answer, as it is it is very short and hard to tell what you are trying to say.  I still haven't figured out what "Try 2d curve makes better corners." means.  Please speak in proper sentances and put a little more effort into your answers, this is a formal question and answer site not a forum.  Thanks!

Comment: English is not my languish! Look at the picture...

Comment: Lynch tried and manage to overstood me! I will try to write more correct...